# Как использовать виртуальную машину?

Tags: virtualbox

помогите пожалуйста запустить виртуальную машину через vagrant

vagrant1.6.3windows7(64)virtualBox 4.1

сделал всё по инструкции, в результате машина запустилась. [скриншот](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/vd.png). но не понятно как с ней работать. в статусе virtualBox написано, что она работает, а где она сама не найду...

Answer (score 1):

Наверное нужно начать с http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/index.html. И почему у вас тип Ubuntu64?

Comment: потому что у меня машина с 64-процессором. не правильно?..

Comment: почему Ubuntu, а не Windows?

Comment: потому что windows у меня основная ОС. я устанавливаю убунту как гостевую